# Cannot pass Request.Url.PathAndQuery value as ReturnUrl query string in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an Asp.net MVC project. I am having a problem with redirect url.

I have a link like this.

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Account/Login&ReturnUrl="+Url.Encode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery))">Log in</a>
```

You can see I added a ReturnUrl query value to the end of url because I want to redirect the user to current url after login.

Request.Url.PathAndQuery return string like this

```
/Item/Details?name=test&id=4
```

When I click the link, it is giving me error:

> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

Url value is like this:

> http://localhost:50489/Account/Login&ReturnUrl=%2fItem%2fDetails%3fname%3dtest%25203%26id%3d4

I cannot use Html.ActionLink because I need to add some html content inside anchor tag.

How can I pass current URL to as ReturnUrl value to log in page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is incorrectly formatted. A query string must begin with a `?`, not a `&`.

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Account/Login?ReturnUrl="+Url.Encode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery))">Log in</a>
```

`&` is for separating query string arguments within the query string.

Comment: Opps! Thanks so much. My mistake and weakness.